# How to create thread that will run function every hour? APS.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How to create  a `thread` or task that will run function every one hour? For example to update data in database that depends on time. I can create thread in method called `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax` file, is that right?

Comment: It can be done using a separate console application. Create console application and schedule it to run every hour.

Comment: My web site hosted on `somee.com` asp.net server, i think it can't run console app. That can be done by `virtual private server`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally: You do not.

You provide an end point (URL) that triggers the operation and call it once per hour. Which obviously can happen automatically.

For example http://www.mywebcron.com/ can call you once per hour without problems.

This avoids all the problems you get once you grow (multiple web servers) or with application restarting.

ASP.NET is a lot - it is NOT a scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a big fan of running scheduled tasks out of asp.net but if you need to you can use the same method SO used to use and fire events on CacheItemRemoved.
You can see Jeff Attwood's blog post [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/). But basically just subscribe to the CacheItemRemoved event and fire your task from there.

```
private static CacheItemRemovedCallback OnCacheRemove = null;

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddTask("DoStuff", 60);
}

private void AddTask(string name, int seconds)
{
    OnCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, seconds, null, 
        DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
        CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
}

public void CacheItemRemoved(string k, object v, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
{
    // do stuff here if it matches our taskname, like WebRequest
    // re-add our task so it recurs
    AddTask(k, Convert.ToInt32(v));
}
```